# Facebook offline_access deprecation and PHP (using curl)

Tags: php, facebook, curl

First of all, I'm sorry for yet another "offline_access" question, but I blame Facebook for being so vague about this. I've been reading so much (here and the official Facebook deprecation "docs") about it and the more I read, the more questions I have.

Our application uses the Facebook API to publish stories from users to their timeline. This is being done from our servers using PHP via curl.

My understanding is that accesstokens cannot be valid for more than 60 days. Does this mean that our users have to come back to our site to re-authorize everytime their token has become invalid? If so, how would services like Foursquare (who have a similar integration as we have) handle this?

Or is it possible to simply request a new token when the Facebook-API replies with a "This token has expired" message?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is covered in the [migration document](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) as scenario 3 or 4 depending on your auth flow

Yes, your users need to come back at least once every 60 days in order for you to have a valid token to take actions on that user's behalf

Answer (score 1):

Of course they have to come back – that’s the whole point of removing offline_access, that apps can’t go on acting forever on behalf of users who maybe don’t even notice it any more.

> Or is it possible to simply request a new token when the Facebook-API replies with a "This token has expired" message?

Not without user interaction. But as far as I understand it, it should be enough to call for example FB.login via the JS SDK when the user is on your page, which will display the popup and immediately close it again if the user is logged in to FB and has still authorized your app, to get a new short-lived access_token, which you can then exchange for a long-lived one.

Comment: I understand. The Facebook's roadmap document doesn't mention anything about the reason of removing the permission.
So we have to find a way to let the user know that they have to come to our site in order to renew the access... which sucks.

Comment: Well, what kind of stories does an app have to publish to their users timeline, if the user hasn’t visited the site for more than 60 days …?

Comment: Oops, didn't see your comment until now. But our service offers users to post their media from our apps to multiple destinations at once. They just set up their destinations once and are then good to go. This change will cause our users to get upset and wonder why their photo hasn't been posted to FB...

Comment: Well, if users are _actively_ using your app when they try to post something, there should be no problem checking if their access token is still valid and if not, just call Facebook login to get a new on; if they have still enabled your Facebook app a simple client-side call to FB.login is enough, it’ll just open the FB popup and close it immediately again (although you have to be aware of popup blockers in their browser, so best to call it on user interaction like clicking on a link/button).

Comment: [cont.] On the other hand, if the user is not actively using your app, because you do all your stuff in the background with no client interaction – then you would have to find a way to notify them that they have to renew their access token. Maybe set up a cron job that’ll look for which tokens are about to expire, and send those users an email with a link to a page where they can renew it.